What is "twisted" in a topological insulator?
The Wikipedia article for Topological Insulators remarks that:

A topological insulator is an insulator for the same reason a "trivial" (ordinary) insulator is: there exists an energy gap between the valence and conduction bands of the material. But in a topological insulator, these bands are, in an informal sense, "twisted", relative to a trivial insulator. The topological insulator cannot be continuously transformed into a trivial one without untwisting the bands, which closes the band gap and creates a conducting state.

I was wondering in what sense one can really call these bands "twisted," especially given that in some topological insulators the band structure itself is identical in the topological phase and trivial phase (e.g. the SSH model). Is anyone able to give even an informal notion or example of what is meant by twisted bands for a topological insulator?

Here is a TED talk Topological insulators: mind the gap!. And here is an explanation of the physics where it helps to already know. Topological Insulators in a Nutshell - Theory and Experiment

To be clear, I'm not really looking for an introduction to topological insulators. These videos are nice, but use the familiar "formal" idea that a topological insulator is one that cannot be connected to the trivial insulator without closing the gap. I am curious how to interpret specifically the idea of "twisting" bands and "untwisting" them.

Though they don't discuss it much, both videos show the bands crossing for edge cases that bound two different regions. This is what they mean by twisted.

Thank you for the follow-up! However, I still don't quite understand. Band Crossings are generic in the subject. What is actually occurring in topological insulators that is special such that we should refer to the bands as being twisted? If it is simply the fact that one set of bands can have a different topological invariant associated with it, then I guess I understand, but was hoping for something different.

This is my naïve take.
We can start with a regular band theory. Assume you have almost free-electrons with a parabolic dispersion. This would lead to the figure below:

Here the gray lines are the parabolic bands (invariant with respect to translation in the reciprocal space). These bands cross at the zone boundaries. Using perturbation theory you open a gap at those crossings.
Now, if you pull atoms apart, those bands will get farther from each other and eventually you fall back to atomic energy levels. If the atoms are infinitely apart, you have vacuum. This is the trivial case.
In a topological insulator, you also have band crossing. But not because of the translation symmetry. In a topological insulator the crossing happens because the bottom of one band is below the top of another. Let me take the blue and red bands and create another picture:

Spin-orbit coupling will take care of lifting that degeneracy in the band crossing and open a gap. You have an insulator. Looking from afar, it is similar to the previous case. You just have a gap. But the bands now are inverted (twisted). You could imagine that each band is built from pieces of two bands.
So what? Let's pull the atoms apart again. Now a different thing happen. When you do that, eventually, the "blue band" will go above the "red band". When that happens, you go from an insulating state to a metallic state (the bands are touching but are not inverted or twisted). The gap has closed. Continue pulling atoms apart and you get back to the regular case.
As I mentioned above, atoms infinitely far apart means vacuum. So that metallic state happens when the material goes from the bulk to vacuum, i.e., the interface. That band inversion produces a material that is insulating in the bulk and metallic at the interface. And that is where all the hype comes from.

A complementary, slightly more abstract explanation:
You are right, the energy of the bands is not twisted at all. Instead, the wave function is twisted.
Consider the SSH model as the simplest example. You can think of solutions of the low-energy wave functions as real unit vectors in 2d. Morally, the wave function in the trivial phase is constant:
$$ \psi = (1,0) $$
On the other hand, in the topological phase the wavefunction doesn't look anythink like a constant, but rather somethink like
$$\psi = (\sin k, \cos k)$$
Generally, it will not be exactly the same description as above for general parameters of the Hamiltonian, but topologically the picture is the same: the wavefunction winds in the topological phase, but not in the trivial phase.
Note that spins are not really arrows in 2D: they can be complex, and should look more like arrows in 3d instead. However, because of the symmetries of the SSH model we could fix the wavefunction to be real, and think about the winding around the origin in 2d space. In general, a TI is then an object of both topology and symmetry: the question you ask is always whether a wavefunction, as a function of k, has some twisting that you cannot undo without breaking the symmetry. Mathrmatically, this question is about the vector bundle describing the wavefunction, and whether it is trivial or not.
